# Run a Python script from Python prompt such that variables are loaded into the interactive environment

Tags: python

Say I have a (somewhat pointless) Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

a = 5
```

Is there a way to run this script from the interactive prompt such that after running if I type `a` I get

```
>>> a
5
```

and not

```
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

More generally, if my script calculates something through a series of steps, is there a way to access that something after the script has finished (in the same kind of manner).

Comment: Does "run this script from the interactive prompt in a shell" mean "run this script from the interactive prompt", or "run this script in a shell and end up in the interactive prompt"? They're contradictory things, and the question seems ambiguous between them. For the first, it's `from pointless import *` (or, very rarely, `execfile`); for the second, it's `python -i pointless.py`.

Comment: I only included the word "shell" to define how I was starting the interactive prompt, so the correct interpretation is, "run this script from the [interactive prompt in a shell]" - i.e. the interactive prompt is running in a shell. I guess in hindsight this is both ambiguous and irrelevant, but I figured there are different ways to run the interactive prompt (e.g. from within other programs) which may change the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import it:

```
from yourscriptname import a
```

Each and every `.py` file in python is a module, and you can simply import it. If the file is called `foo.py`, import `foo`.

Comment: What about if you're actually calculating something (i.e. it's not a hardcoded value) [oh snap, never mind]